# Can I add additional field (metadata) to thrift message?

Tags: java, thrift

I have generated client and server.
I need to add one more field to message in client and read it in server.
I think about to decorate `TProtocol` on client side and `TProcessor` on server side. E.g.:

```
// Client:
TTransport transport = new TSocket("localhost", 8888);
transport.open();
TProtocol protocol = new DecoratedProtocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));

// Server:
 TServerTransport transport = new TServerSocket(8888);
 TServer server = new TSimpleServer(new Args(transport).processor(new DecoratedProcessor(...)));
```

But I'm not sure what to do inside `DecoratedProtocol` and `DecoratedProcessor`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [solution to add message meta data called the `THeaderProtocol`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2423), but AFAIK right now this is only implemented for C++. That could be a starting point to implement the same for Java.

EDIT: I just noticed that fbthrift [seems to implement THeaderProtocol for Java](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1468950976659943/under-the-hood-building-and-open-sourcing-fbthrift/) already.